# How to close files through terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

My computer is Mac. I want to know how to close files like pdfs, images, applications through terminal. Sometimes, I open so many pdfs images and applications, I want to use terminal to close them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Preview to open the PDFs, images, etc, and *if* there are no other files open in Preview that you need to leave open, just type `killall preview` in the Terminal to kill Preview.  Of course, you could do that with your mouse (or Cmd-Q on your keyboard too), so I'm not sure what that really saves you.

There's a command called `lsof` which should help *list* the open files too, can't remember if if shows you the process that using the file.  But, if it does, you could pipe the output of `lsof` through `sed` and `kill` to kill the process, but once again you have to be OK with closing all of the files in use by that process (app).

Answer (score 0):

You can close documents through terminal by killing the process displaying it. Use the `ps` command to find the process, then use the `kill` command to terminate it.